# How to add schema in OpenLDAP over AD referral

Tags: openldap

I'm not sure this is possible or where to look for the functionality.

Given an Active Directory (or any other LDAP really), can I stand up OpenLDAP in front of it with a referral but add schema on the OpenLDAP end?

More specifically: Use OpenLDAP to add POSIX schema to an LDAP server that does not support it.

The motivations for this are:
* PoC testing before making schema changes to main LDAP Directory
* Better understand how referrals/proxies and OpenLDAP work in general.

(I am familiar with configuring OpenLDAP enough to have a functional multi-master cluster running, but just barely;-)

Comment: It looks like the Translucent Proxy Overlay and an LDAP Backend will accomplish this. I have yet to try to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to compose an entry by gluing a part fetched from a remote LDAP plus some attributes kept in a local repository?

Translucent Proxy OpenLDAP overlay can do something similar.

Comment: Yes. I want to add attributes with openldap that the backend ldap does not provide and return a composite to the client, although the client would have no indication it's a composite.

Comment: So Translucent Proxy overlay may be your cup of tea.